# Deleting polygons that overlap specific attributes?

Tags: arcmap

I have a raster dataset with specific features and values. I also have a dataset that is made up of several hundred small polygons identifying specific features. How do I remove polygons that don't intersect specific values in the raster dataset?

Answer (score 1):

You can aproach that in several ways. Here is one:

1. Filter your raster keeping just cells with the values that you are interested in (you can use raster calculator for example).
2. Transform your raster into polygons.
3. Get those polygons that intersect with those created in step 2. Use intersection or select by location.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do I use raster calculator to filter by attribute? From my understanding you can only perform operations the entire file, I don't know how to filter based on attribute without using the 'Select by Attribute' feature. I'm trying now to convert the whole file into a shapefile using raster to polygon in arctoolbox, but the process completes in one second and the file doesn't exist.